# How can I search in a specific column using the jQuery DataTables plugin?

Tags: jquery, arrays, jquery-plugins, datatables

I used the `jquery dataTable plugin` to show a table which contains (username, dates, and email).
I want to disable the filtering/search for the username and email columns and enable just the search for the dates. when I click on the search field I'll open a calendar to choose the date which we will look for.

I just want to use this plugin for filtering only dates, basically. Can this be done?

-edit--

I read the docs :[dateRange](http://jquery-datatables-column-filter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/dateRange.html) But It doesn't work for me I added the

```
('.dataTable').dataTable()
    .columnFilter({
        sPlaceHolder: "head:before",
        aoColumns: [null, { type: "date-range" }, null]
    });
```

And I duplicated the headers but I can't get the date fields or any other field to search the data into.

Comment: read the docs on configuring columns and options for columns

Comment: Thank you I read it . But I get no result. I added ` $('#example').dataTable()
    .columnFilter({  sPlaceHolder: "head:before",
     aoColumns: [  null,
            { type: "date-range" },
                                       null
      ]

  });` But I can't see the date range filter.

Comment: you have misunderstood what the filter is for in column config

Answer (score 15):

You can use [`column().search()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/column().search()) to obtain search on specific value, ex:

```
  var table = $('#example-table').DataTable();

  $('#search-input').on('change', function(){

    table
    .column(4)
    .search(this.value)
    .draw();

  });
```

[Working Demo](http://codepen.io/MWalid/pen/Jhlet)

[Refrences](http://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html)

Comment: The search for :2009/01/12 doesn't work in this demo and I want to search for the date ranges like this : http://jquery-datatables-column-filter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/dateRange.html .Can you help me please?

Comment: Please [check the demo](http://codepen.io/MWalid/pen/Jhlet) again it was an issue with the markups not the Javascript code, about the addon you mentioned, it's for DataTables 1.09 I don't think it's compatible with the current version (1.11) that's why it doesn't work when you tried, but you can still make same behavior by extending `$.fn.dataTable.ext.search` function, please check this [example](http://www.datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html).

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing this and one of them is mentioned follow which i personally felt is the easiest one, with the following you define which columns NOT TO LOOK FOR while searching using datatable search.

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
'columnDefs' : [
        { 
           'searchable'    : false, 
           'targets'       : [0,2,3] 
        },
    ]
} );
```

Comment: targets define column #  0,2,3 means not to look for these columns