# Limit searchable columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, datatables

I am using the following code to add multiple search parameters to my results but I do not want to search on all results just certain columns but I can't figure out how to only display the search box on selected columns.  I tried using columndefs but I could not get it to work.  Any suggestions?

````
                .columns()
                .every(function () {
                    var that = this;
 
                    $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change clear', function () {
                        if (that.search() !== this.value) {
                            that.search(this.value).draw();
                }
                    });
                });
        },
            buttons: [ {
                extend: "edit",
                editor: editor
            }, ]
        } );```
````

Comment: Please consider adding a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Replace `.columns()` with a function that just returns the searchable columns.

Comment: This is usually handled by the following DataTables option: [`columns.searchable`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.searchable). But in your case, with `.columns()`, you can also provide a [column-selector](https://datatables.net/reference/type/column-selector#array) as an array of values - for example: `.columns( [0, 1] )`. There are various other formats if you don't want to use an array.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How can I search in a specific column using the jQuery DataTables plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24790946/12567365).